# insert table from different database

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, dblink

#### SQL

```
INSERT INTO t_publikasi
  ("idPublikasi","kdBahanPustaka","bulanTerbit", "tahunTerbit", "noUrutBI",
   "pdfDir", "judul")
SELECT * 
  FROM dblink('dbname=perpus2 port=5432 user=dbdev password=develop',
              'SELECT '113' || substring("no_pustaka",4,2) as bb ||
                      substring("no_pustaka",6,2) as cc ||
                      substring("no_pustaka",9,4) as dd,
                      '113', 
                      substring("no_pustaka",4,2) as bb,
                      substring("no_pustaka",6,2) as cc,
                      substring("no_pustaka",9,4) as dd,
                      "file_pdf","judul"
                 FROM kuesioner 
             ORDER BY bb, cc, dd') AS kuesioner (
    id varchar(10), 
    kd varchar(10),
    bln varchar(10),
    thn varchar(10),
    urut varchar(10),
    file_pdf varchar(50), 
    judul varchar(50));
```

#### ERRORS

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "113"
LINE 1: ...2 port=5432 user=dbdev password=develop','SELECT '113' || su...

                                                            ^
ERROR: syntax error at or near "113"
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: You might wish to change the password on the `dbdev` account of your `perpus2` database...

Comment: you need to quote those quotes...

Comment: Start with removing the column aliases to the first column in your dblink statement...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : i have removed column aliases, but i want to merge with '.'... if in one database select 113 || '.' from kuesioner is works but when i do it in diference database it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

change

'SELECT '113'

to

'SELECT 113

or

'SELECT "113"

Hope it helps.

Comment: `SELECT "113"` is invalid SQL syntax as character literals cannot be enclosed in double quotes. Double quotes are only used to quote object names (columns, tables, ...)

Answer (score 0):

When you write `'SELECT '113'||` you are terminating the second parameter for the dblink() call that contains the SELECT statement and then you start a numeric literal that is 113.

`'SELECT 113` works because it will select a number instead of a character literal. 
The `||` operator will then silently cast that back to a character value.

The proper way to embedd a single quote in a character literal is to write two single quotes:

`, 'SELECT ''113''||substring(... '`

Answer (score 0):

Use `E` or dollar quoting.

```
...
FROM dblink('dbname=perpus2 port=5432 user=dbdev password=develop',
          $my_dblink_arg$SELECT '113' ||
...
      FROM kuesioner 
         ORDER BY bb, cc, dd$my_dblink_arg$) AS kuesioner
...
```